# ModelBuilder, which tool should I use to rename layers with value from table?

Tags: modelbuilder, splitting, iterator

I have a ModelBuilder tool with an iterator that splits a feature into multiple shapefiles based on a attribute field. The problem I'm running into is instead of simply using the number values for naming, I would like to replace the number with what the layer physically represents. For example a few of the new shapefiles are

> M4ExportLine_Layer149.shp
>
> M4ExportLine_Layer150.shp
>
> M4ExportLine_Layer153.shp

I would like these to be named respectively

> M4ExportLine_LayerBuriedFiber.shp
>
> M4ExportLine_LayerAerialFiber.shp
>
> M4ExportLine_LayerOverlashFiber.shp

And there are quite a few more that need renamed in that fashion.
The problem is there is only layer numbers in the attribute table and nothing represents the physical name except for the legend.
Here is the model I have so far 
[Model][1]

[image: Model]

Answer (score 1):

This seems like something that should be very easy but requires an extra step.

The solution I came up with is to create a dictionary.csv file in excel containing a "Key" (layer #), and a string (name).

Use the table select tool to select rows from the dictionary where the key is equal to the layer #. This will output a new table containing only a single row. Next, you can use the model only tool "Get Field Value" to get the "string" field from the table, which can then be used in your file name.

Comment: OK, I will try this. It will take a bit because there are about 450 layers! Thanks!

Comment: OK I got the dictionary done, I did the tools that you recommended, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the values from the dictionary table into the iterator function. New Model http://i.imgur.com/RRZsdZm.jpg and example from dictionary table. http://i.imgur.com/2kDt299.jpg

Comment: You should be able to use the variables enclosed within % signs within your file names. You should rename the variable "Value (2)" to something like "Name". The input to table select for the key should then be %Value%, and the name of the file output by copy features should be M4ExportLine_Layer%Name%.shp

Comment: OK I tried that, I'm sorry maybe I'm not getting something right, I'm rather new to modelbuilder. I got an error ERROR 000210: Cannot create output C:\Users\morij\Desktop\Projects\M4Testing_062015\ModelTest\FinalExportByLayer\M4ExportLine_Layer%Name%.shp
ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters
Failed to execute (Copy Features).
Failed at Tue Jun 23 09:13:02 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0.05 seconds). It seems like the Value (2) keeps changing it's name back to Value (2) from "Name"

Comment: Interesting. Not sure why it keeps changing its name back. Have you tried making the file name:
M4‌​ExportLine_Layer%Value (2)%.shp

Comment: Ya I tried that a bit ago, Got this error. Start Time: Tue Jun 23 09:30:10 2015
ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters
Item not found in this collection.
Failed to execute (Make Feature Layer).
Failed at Tue Jun 23 09:30:10 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0.16 seconds)
Failed to execute (Iterate Feature Selection).
Failed at Tue Jun 23 09:30:10 2015 (Elapsed                      Do you think I need a different type of iterator? I think part of the problem is that they aren't  "connected" in any way. http://i.imgur.com/42MqVki.jpg

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what is causing the issue. I'm not sure this is the issue, but maybe this link will help http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w0000007r000000